# ng-repeat run function for every row?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a ng-repeat and I need to run a function to get some additional data/few calculations for every row.

Something like this

```
<div id="complaintstable">
            <table>                  
                <tr ui-sref="complaints.details({ id: item.Id })" ng-repeat="item in list" class="item" ng-class-odd="'odd'" ng-class-even="'even'" ng-init="rowInit(item)">
                    <td>
                        {{item.ConsumerName}}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{dayspan}}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{item.ConsumerCity}}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{item.Agent.First_Name}} {{item.Agent.Last_Name}}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{compname}}
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        {{item.DateOpenedDisplay}}
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
```

And then in the directives controller

```
   $scope.rowInit = function (row) {
                  $scope.dayspan = someAJAXCall();
                  $scope.compname = someCalculation();
                  console.log("here");
              }
```

Obviously the problem with this is that `rowInit` gets evaluated in the controller scope and no in the `ng-repeat` scope, so `dayspan` and `compname` get overwritten. How would I go about evaluating `rowInit` in the `ng-repeat` scope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate your list and do the calc for each row, add the data to the row, then display item.compname and item.dayspan in your markup.

```
$scope.list.forEach(
    function(item) {
      item.dayspan = someAJAXCall();
      item.compname = someCalc();
    }
);
```

Note, a boat load of AJAX calls concurrently is problematic - but that's not a problem asked about in your question.